# Count the number of consecutive entries fulfilling a condition within a GROUP BY

Tags: postgresql

I've got a list of users who are behind on their bills, and I want to generate an entry for each of them that says how many consecutive bills they've been behind on. So here's the table:

```
user |  bill_date | outstanding_balance
---------------------------------------
 a   | 2017-03-01 |        90
 a   | 2016-12-01 |        60
 a   | 2016-09-01 |        30
 b   | 2017-03-01 |        50
 b   | 2016-12-01 |        0
 b   | 2016-09-01 |        40
 c   | 2017-03-01 |        0
 c   | 2016-12-01 |        0
 c   | 2016-09-01 |        1
```

And I want a query that would generate the following table:

```
user | consecutive_billing_periods_behind
-----------------------------------------
  a  |               3
  b  |               1
  a  |               0
```

In other words, if you've paid up at any point, I want to ignore all of the earlier entries, and only count how many billing periods you've been behind since you've been last paid up. How do I do this most simply?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, first you need to find the last date that any given customer paid their bill so the last date their outstanding balance was 0. You can do this by this subquery:

```
            (SELECT
              user1,
              bill_date AS no_outstanding_bill_date
            FROM table1
            WHERE outstanding_balance = 0)
```

Then you need get the last bill date and create field for each row if they are outstanding bill. Then filter the rows between the last clear day to last bill date of each customer by this where clause:

```
WHERE bill_date >= last_clear_day AND bill_date <= last_bill_date
```

Then if you put the pieces together you can have the results by this query:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  user1,
  sum(is_outstanding_bill)
  OVER (
    PARTITION BY user1 ) AS consecutive_billing_periods_behind
FROM (
       SELECT
         user1,
         last_value(bill_date)
         OVER (
           PARTITION BY user1
           ORDER BY bill_date
           ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS last_bill_date,
         CASE WHEN outstanding_balance > 0
           THEN 1
         ELSE 0 END                                                   AS is_outstanding_bill,
         bill_date,
         outstanding_balance,
         nvl(max(t2.no_outstanding_bill_date)
             OVER (
               PARTITION BY user1 ), min(bill_date)
             OVER (
               PARTITION BY user1 ))                                  AS last_clear_day

       FROM table1 t1
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT
                      user1,
                      bill_date AS no_outstanding_bill_date
                    FROM table1
                    WHERE outstanding_balance = 0) t2 USING (user1)
     ) table2
WHERE bill_date >= last_clear_day AND bill_date <= last_bill_date
```

Since we are using distinct you will not need the group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  user,
  count(case when min_balance > 0 then 1 end)
    as consecutive_billing_periods_behind
from
(
  select
    user,
    min(outstanding_balance)
      over (partition by user order by bill_date) as min_balance
  from tbl
)
group by user
```

Or:

```
select
  user,
  count(*)
    as consecutive_billing_periods_behind
from
(
  select
    user,
    bill_date,
    max(case when outstanding_balance = 0 then bill_date) over
      (partition by user)
      as max_bill_date_with_zero_balance
  from tbl
)
where
  -- If user has no outstanding_balance = 0, then
  max_bill_date_with_zero_balance is null
  -- Count all rows in this case.

  -- Otherwise
  or
  -- count rows with
  bill_date > max_bill_date_with_zero_balance
group by user
```